# Does a process with CAP_SETUID and CAP_SETGID can always gain full root privileges?

Tags: linux, root, privileges, user-groups

If I have an executable file with CAP_SETUID and CAP_SETGID set inside xattrs file’s attributes.
Will I get full root privileges if such executable call `setuid()`;`setreuid()`;`setresuid()`;`setfsuid()` with the value 0 ? Or will I only be identified as the root user without having the ability to do things like opening privileged ports ?

Of course, the executable is initially launched from the guest account with uid and gid set to 1002 and with SeLinux disabled on the whole system.